# Scheduler MVC5 ASP.Net Save Database events

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5

I have followed this tutorial to create a scheduler :
http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/Appointment-Calendar-in-ASP-NET-MVC5.aspx

But there is no data saving to my database; my table is empty

Where should I callthe method Save ?

Comment: You should post your question on that blog site.

Comment: on which action you are unable to save data ?

Comment: In my method Index there is no call of the method Save ()